# how do I log the data on to a dash app using python

Tags: javascript, python, plotly-dash

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash
import sys

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Interval(id='interval1', interval=1000,
n_intervals=0),
    dcc.Interval(id='interval2', interval=1 * 1000,
n_intervals=0),
    html.H1(id='div-out', children=''),
    html.Iframe(id='console-out',srcDoc='',style={'width':
'100%','height':400})
])

@app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('div-out',
'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('interval1', 'n_intervals')])
def update_interval(n):
    return 'hello'

@app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('console-out',
'srcDoc'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('interval2', 'n_intervals')])
def update_output(n):
    data = ''
    for i in range(n):
        data=data+'printing' + '<BR>'

    return data


app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I am using Dash for python as a standalone app I want to log the data on to (http://127.0.0.1:8050/logger). The above is the code that I tried by browsing. Is there a way where I can directly print the message onto the app so that I don't need to update the list every time? without using an iframe.
Any help will be appreciated Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: Thank you it really helped

Comment: @BasvanderLinden if its possible can you please look into this also   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68305205/how-do-i-make-line-graph-in-dash-plotly-to-only-update-the-latest-values-instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

printing = html.P(["printing", html.Br()])

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Interval(id="interval", interval=1000, n_intervals=0),
        html.Div(id="content"),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("content", "children"),
    Input("interval", "n_intervals"),
    State("content", "children"),
)
def update_output(interval, content):
    if not content:
        return [printing]

    return content + [printing]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

So the idea of the code above is to create a container element that will hold the text elements. Then we can create a callback that is called every second using the `Interval` component. This callback uses the `children` property `State` of the container to take all the current children and add another element and return the result.

Be aware that this will keep adding elements to the DOM forever. So at a certain number of elements you might want to make it stop updating.